# Changing the Format of a Column from QUERY function in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am currently using this formula to list users that have a Birthday this month

```
=QUERY(Data!$A:$K, "Select C,D,J WHERE Month(J)+1 matches '"& Month(Today()) &"' ", 1 )
```

I get a list of users that list their First Name, Last Name, and Birthdate for users that have a birthday in the current month.

Is it possible to return the 3rd column (birthdate) in a different format? Such as let's say I want to use Text(J, "mm-dd")?

I tried

```
=QUERY(Data!$A:$K, "Select C,D,TEXT(J, '"mm-dd"' WHERE Month(J)+1 matches '"& Month(Today()) &"' ", 1 )
```

But I get a formula parse error. I am guessing I can't do formulas within the query, but just wanted to see if anyone has input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends... you can use `QUERY` parameter `format`

> [image]

so it would be:

```
=QUERY(Data!$A:$K, 
 "select C,D,J 
  where month(J)+1 matches '"&MONTH(TODAY())&"'
  format J 'mm-dd'", 1)
```

but this depends on your dataset...

Comment: Followup for you, So I wanted to sort and tried to add ORDER BY in there, but it doesn't seem sorted. I am assuming because it is taking the year into consideration. Is there a way around this?

Comment: try: `=QUERY(QUERY(Data!$A:$K, 
 "select C,D,J 
  where month(J)+1 matches '"&MONTH(TODAY())&"'
  format J 'mm-dd'", 1), "order by Col10",  1)` but it rly depends on the dataset you have